# Backend vs. Hosting Difference?

Tags: android, mobile, hosting, firebase, backend

I am creating a social media app and going to be using Firebase for my backend. I know this might be a simple question but would i still need to host my app on some hosting service if I'm using Firebase for backend? Kind of confused on hosting vs backend.

Comment: By "app" do you mean the client app that installs on a mobile device?  If so, you'll need some method of distribution, whether it's an app store or something else.  If not, please explain what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If by "app" you mean the server-side part of your social app and not the client-side (which is the Android application you will upload on Google Play), Firebase will do the work for you, specially while you're developing or you application is not so popular (yet) and used.

If you look at the pricing plans (https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html), you would see the Hacker plan is free and it will give you some data and hosting storage and transfer. In case you would need more you'll have to pay them choosing one of other planes.

According to this link (https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/custom-domain.html), it seems you could also set your own custom domain for hosting your static contents, like images. Please notice this option is available for paid plans only.

So, to summarize, you can start developing using Firebase with the free Hacker plan and you don't have to worry about anything else, just use their API as explained in the documentation. Be aware, if you exceed the limits, you could have to pay or receive error/data exceeded responses from the service.

Of course, please design your application in order to decouple it as much as possible from Firebase specifics, because maybe one day you will have or decide to switch to another service and it will require less work to do that.

I hope it helps.

(I'm not affiliated or work for Firebase).

Comment: There are no overage fees on the hacker plan.